# SQL Server : how to insert Identity in existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP6
(ENO INT CONSTRAINT PRKEY PRIMARY KEY, ENAME VARCHAR(15))
```

After creation of the table, I want to add `IDENTITY` to the `ENO` column. Can I add `IDENTITY` and can I remove `IDENTITY` for it?

Comment: IS YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY BROKEN!?

Comment: @Marc_s: Why do you use the flag of Nova Scotia as your avatar? I thought you were in NS. (Sorry, don't know of another way to contact you  :o)

Answer (score 1):

No, you **CANNOT** add or remove `IDENTITY` from an existing column.

If you forgot to make your `ENO` column an `IDENTITY`, then you must drop the table and re-create it with the correct settings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you **cannot do this**. Best option is to create a new identity column and copy the data over using an identity insert command (if you indeed want to keep the old values).

[This Article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1397/add-or-drop-identity-property-for-an-existing-sql-server-column/) explains this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to Create Table is using Designer. Install Sql Management Studio and you are up.
Here are two quick tips:

1. Connect to db using Management Studio. Right Click on Tables folder. Choose Add new table and design the entire table schema . Right clicking again on column will give you options for PKEY, relationships indexes etc and many more.
2. More quicker. Open Database Diagrams and Add/Modify everything literally pictorially. But beware any changes commited in the database diagram will affect the database schema too.